# aireplay-ng --fakeauth issue with deauth packet

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I am new to Kali Linux and I want to check if ethical hacking and pentesting is my cup of tea. I'm trying to associate my wireless adapter with an AP via `aireplay-ng --fakeauth`, but every time I use this I get a deauthentication packet. I tried this with WEP and WPA2, and result was the same.

```
aireplay-ng --fakeauth 30 -a <AP MAC addr> -h <Adapter MAC addr> <interface name>

Sending Authentication Request (Open System) [ACK]
Authentication successful
Sending Association Request [ACK]
Association successful :-) (AID: 1)

Sending keep-alive packet [ACK]
Got a deauthentication packet! (Waiting 3 seconds)
```

Well, I can't use `reaver` and ARP replay because of this.
I typed `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and still the same.
Any idea how to solve this problem? Could it be the fault of my adapter or AP settings?

Adapter: TL-WN727N

Comment: Have you already read the [documentation](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=fake_authentication) what fakeauth actually does?

Comment: Yes I read this, and I know this only allow us to associate wireless adapter with AP, and this is required to get more IV from idling networks with WEP. I only did not try to decrese keep-alive packet sending time, but I don`t know if this can help.